# Selenium verify file download java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-ide

I am trying to use selenium to verify that a file has been properly downloaded from a download link. I am creating an automated test script that needs to click the download link and i need to verify that the file has been downloaded. Is there any way to do so?

My code is something like this.

```
Page Results = new Page(driver);
if (Results.downloadLinkExists()) {
    Results.downloadlink();
//the file name is a very long url, so i am trying to shorten it to the name of the file.
    String filename = Results.downloadname();   

    int startPoint = filename.indexOf("fileName=");
    int endPoint = filename.indexOf("&", startPoint);
    System.out.println(filename.substring(startPoint + 9, endPoint)); 
    // the result system print at this point is something like '12345678.pdf'

    File downloadfile = new File("C:\\Downloads\\" + filename.substring(startPoint + 9, endPoint) );

    
    if (downloadfile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("it exists");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Does not exist");
    }
    
    }else {
        System.out.println("There is no download link avaliable");
    }
```

The webpage file has the these funcions. The class of the webpage file is "Page"

```
public boolean downloadLinkExists() {
        try { driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'.pdf')]"));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }


public void downloadlink() {
    WebElement download = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'.pdf')]"));
    download.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
public String downloadname() {
    WebElement download = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'.pdf')]"));
    return download.getAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: What is the current problem here? Did you downloaded but didn't verify? Or you couldn't download yet?

Comment: I can download the file but i dont have a way to verify that the file is downloaded properly. Normally i would use screencapture to check but the download popup does not appear in screencapture

Comment: I think the problem is your download path. It's `" C:\Downloads\ "` . I think Windows download folder like this `" C:\Users\{UserName}\Downloads "` . Can you print the `downloadfile` variable path to check manually?

Comment: After the file is downloaded just use `Boolean fileExists = file.exists();`. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-exists-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: @halilibrahimbinol
that was the problem. thanks!